# Maintain user permission on web application with REST API

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, reactjs, web-applications

How to manage user permission on web applications based on REST API. I mean all action on API required selected permission such as **manage_posts** or **manage_users**. It's easy to check the permissions on API side on every call and return non authorized when user tries to do things he shouldn't do. But on web application side we have to hide button/disallow to enter certain address.

Querying for all required permission each page view change is not good in my opinion, but keeping all permissions on localstorage/session doesn't seem to be good.

**Idea 1:**

```
API:
/user/current_user
    {
        name: "Name",
        email: "name@domain.com",
        permissions: ["manage_posts", "manage_users"]
    }
```

And having this information we store it inside local storage/session and this is used for toggling buttons and router based access. Additionally all API endpoints would also check the required permission and return 403 code when FORBIDDEN and application will manage to redirect to non authorized page if 403 occurs.

**Idea 2:**

```
API
POST:/user/check_permission
{
    status: "OK"
}
```

This requires web application query API each time web application requires checking the permission status. It's "safer" but I don't think it's good.